# In Rust, how to create a globally shared singleton with `OnceLock`?

Tags: rust, concurrency, thread-safety, static-variables

Assuming that we need to define a singleton with global read access with thread safety, the canonical method is to use `OnceLock`:

```
/// A synchronization primitive which can be written to only once.
///
/// This type is a thread-safe [`OnceCell`], and can be used in statics.

static i1: OnceLock<Box<u64>> = OnceLock::new(); // this works
static i2: OnceLock<Box<dyn Sized>> = OnceLock::new(); // this doesnt:
```

the second line throw several errors that doesn't make sense:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Sized` cannot be made into an object
   --> src/lib.rs:118:25
    |
118 | static i2: OnceLock<Box<dyn Sized>> = OnceLock::new();
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^ `Sized` cannot be made into an object
    |
    = note: the trait cannot be made into an object because it requires `Self: Sized`
    = note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
```

Sized is a trait that has dynamic size, but Box is just a smart reference that points to a dynamically allocated struct later, and it is not even initialised in this definition, so why do I need make it into an object?

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn Sized + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:118:12
    |
118 | static i2: OnceLock<Box<dyn Sized>> = OnceLock::new();
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn Sized + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn Sized + 'static)`
    = note: required for `Unique<(dyn Sized + 'static)>` to implement `Sync`
note: required because it appears within the type `Box<(dyn Sized + 'static)>`
   --> /home/peng/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:195:12
    |
195 | pub struct Box<
    |            ^^^
    = note: required for `OnceLock<Box<(dyn Sized + 'static)>>` to implement `Sync`
    = note: shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync`
```

"Thread Safety" & "static" are literally in the documentation of "OnceLock", how could it be considered unsafe?

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn Sized + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:118:12
    |
118 | static i2: OnceLock<Box<dyn Sized>> = OnceLock::new();
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn Sized + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn Sized + 'static)`
    = note: required for `Unique<(dyn Sized + 'static)>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `Box<(dyn Sized + 'static)>`
   --> /home/peng/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:195:12
    |
195 | pub struct Box<
    |            ^^^
    = note: required for `OnceLock<Box<(dyn Sized + 'static)>>` to implement `Sync`
    = note: shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync`
```

any static binding only has 1 replica in memory and is used by all threads in a process, there is no need to send them between threads like some distributed computing framework. How could the compiler never realised that?

So these 3 errors all appears to be clueless, how can I bypass these errors and make the static binding work with minimal overhead?

Comment: What do you mean by writing `dyn Sized`? Maybe you need `dyn Any`?

Comment: Probably `dyn Any + Send + Sync`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dyn Sized` contradicts itself, `Sized` means, all items of a type have a statically known size, but `Sized` is implemented for a variety of types, `()`, `u8`, `u16`, … all with a different size, that means `dyn Sized` could have a size of 0 bytes, 1 byte, 2 bytes, … and you can change the underlying type at runtime so it is **not** statically known.
That means a trait object (because it can be any type it's trait is implemented for) cannot implement `Sized`, but implementing the named trait is all we know a trait object does. In other words `dyn Sized` does not implement `Sized` but must implement `Sized` at the same time.

The second and third error boil down to `statics` needing to be `Sync` (they can be accessed from any thread and `Sync` is the trait that tells the compiler it's safe to do so) but [`OnceCell` only implements `Sync` if it's contents are `Sync + Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html#impl-Sync-for-OnceLock%3CT%3E). The [source of `OnceCell` explains](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sync/once_lock.rs.html#411-415)<sup>*</sup>:

> ```rust
> // Why do we need `T: Send`?
> // Thread A creates a `OnceLock` and shares it with
> // scoped thread B, which fills the cell, which is
> // then destroyed by A. That is, destructor observes
> // a sent value.
> ```

A trait object however only implements the traits it lists, so `dyn Trait` does not implement either `Send` or `Sync`.

You can achive what you seem to want simply by specifying an [object safe trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) and add the `Send` and `Sync` bounds to the trait object as well. For example with `std::any::Any` for any `T: 'static` type:

```rust
static i2: OnceLock<Box<dyn Any + Send + Sync>> = OnceLock::new();
```

---

<sup>*) That doesn't apply for your specific case, but does explain why `OnceCell` needs it's content to implement `Send`, to get around it one would need a distinct `LeakingOnceCell` which does not drop it's contents, it's usefulness seems questionable to me.</sup>